# How can I return an array of structs using a Chainlink Direct Request job?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, chainlink

I'm trying to return an array of custom type (struct) **MyStruct[]** of ambiguous size to my Chainlink consumer contract, and am having trouble developing the appropriate job config (TOML) for it.

I'm aware of the gas concerns here, but would like to ignore this for now, as I'll be handling this via separate circuit breakers in the API endpoint.

I have a consumer contract that looks similar to this (pseudo-code):

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ConfirmedOwner.sol";

contract ConsumerContract is ChainlinkClient, ConfirmedOwner {

    . . .

    struct MyStruct {
        uint a;
        uint b;
        string x;
    }

    MyStruct[] public result;

    function request() public {
    
        Chainlink.Request memory req = buildOperatorRequest(jobId, this.fulfill.selector);      

        // (add parameters)
       
        // Send the request to the Chainlink oracle
        sendOperatorRequest(req, fee);
    }

    function fulfill(bytes32 requestId, bytes[] memory _result) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(requestId) {

        emit RequestFulfilled(requestId, _result);

        // Process the response
        for(uint i = 0; i < _result.length; i++){
            MyStruct memory myStruct = abi.decode(_result[i], (MyStruct));
            result.push(myStruct);
        }

    }

    . . .
```

Example response from API endpoint (JSON representation of an unknown number of structs). Since I have control over the API endpoint, I can format this response however necessary:

```
[
   [
      0,
      1,
      "myString-1"
   ],
   [
      2,
      3,
      "myString-2"
   ]
   . . .
]
```

Example job TOML (not working, but I took a stab at what I think it should look like):

```
type = "directrequest"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "my-job"
forwardingAllowed = false
maxTaskDuration = "0s"
contractAddress = "XXX"
minContractPaymentLinkJuels = "0"
observationSource = """

    decode_log   [type="ethabidecodelog"
                  abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)"
                  data="$(jobRun.logData)"
                  topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"]

    decode_cbor  [type="cborparse" data="$(decode_log.data)"]

    fetch [type="http" method=GET url="$(decode_cbor.url)" allowunrestrictednetworkaccess="true"]

    encode_data [type="ethabiencode"
                abi="(bytes32 requestId, bytes[] _data)"
                data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"_data\\": [$(fetch)]}"
                ]

    encode_tx  [type="ethabiencode"
                abi="fulfillOracleRequest2(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes calldata data)"
                data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"payment\\": $(decode_log.payment), \\"callbackAddress\\": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), \\"callbackFunctionId\\": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), \\"expiration\\": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), \\"data\\": $(encode_data)}"
                ]

    submit_tx    [type="ethtx" to="XXX" data="$(encode_tx)"]

    decode_log -> decode_cbor -> fetch -> encode_data -> encode_tx -> submit_tx
"""
```

While the Chainlink job pipeline completes interally, the error occurs during the fulfill transaction, causing the fulfill transaction to fail (likely because my consumer contract's fulfill() function errors out trying to translate the bytes[] response into a `struct[]`).

I checked out the Chainlink documentation, but nowhere can I find any information on how to return a custom data type (ie, struct) using a Direct Request job.

UPD: After scouring the internet, there is a similar question here, but it does not relate to an **array** of structs, and the struct included is quite basic (contains only one field):
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/148499/chainlink-any-api-ethabiencode-while-parsing-abi-string-bad-abi-specification

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think encode_data can be used to encode an array. Can you try to encode the array of struct with `encode_large`? In order to use encode_large, please replace the codes

```
    encode_data [type="ethabiencode"
                abi="(bytes32 requestId, bytes[] _data)"
                data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"_data\\": [$(fetch)]}"
                ]
```

to

```
    encode_large [type="ethabiencode"
                abi="(bytes32 requestId, bytes[] _data)"
                data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"_data\\": $(fetch)}"
                ]
```

In addition, in your TOML file, there is no `parse` to parse the data you fetched from API in `fetch` and no path is provided either. You are trying to parse the entire JSON file, so please make sure that you get the correct value. You can add a `parse` with the codes below:

```
parse        [type="jsonparse" path="$(decode_cbor.path)" data="$(fetch)"]
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Won't the two job tasks you've posted above (`encode_data` and `encode_large`) have the same behavior, as they are both of type `ethabiencode`? What you've changed is the name:
https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-nodes/oracle-jobs/all-tasks#eth-abi-encode-task

Comment: Also, I omitted the `parse` task in my example for brevity, but please consider it present in my real-world implementation. Thanks

Comment: oops, I thought you were using `abi="(bytes32 requestId, bytes _data)"`, just try to update it to `abi="(bytes32 requestId, bytes[] _data)". You are right,` encode_data and `encode_large` represents the same task. I can get the array of uint256 successfully but have not tried the array of struct. Can you provide a API you are using and I can give it a try.

Comment: Thanks. You could send a POST request to https://httpbin.org/post with the following body: `{"data":[[0,1,"myString-1"],[2,3,"myString-2"]]}`. This service will echo the provided body back to you at the following JSON path: `json,data`, which essentially is an array of 2 objects that could theoretically be mapped into an array of `MyStruct` (uint,uint,string). For the record, I am definitely able to return an array of uint256 - it's specifically a custom data type (struct) that I am having issues with!